# How to modify the quantity of a commerceItem in the current order in ATG?

Tags: atg

I want to modify the quantity of commerceItem in the current order using CartModifierFormHandler.

I have passed `catalogRefId` & `new quantity` 
then called either `CartModifierFormHandler.setOrderByCommerceId` or `setOrder`
but it modified all items' quantity besides the one I want to modify. Could someone tell me what's wrong or how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the out-of-the-box `setOrderByCommerceId` method (which is definitely the way to go since it already takes care of all the transaction related code) then you need to keep the following in mind.

`setOrderByCommerceId` will call `modifyOrderByCommerceId` in the out-of-the-box `CartModifierFormHandler`. This in turn calls `getQuantity`

```
public long getQuantity(String pCatalogRefId, DynamoHttpServletRequest pRequest, DynamoHttpServletResponse pResponse) throws ServletException, IOException, NumberFormatException {
    Object value = pRequest.getParameter(pCatalogRefId);
    if (value != null) {
        return Long.parseLong(value.toString());
    }
    return getQuantity();
}
```

So from this snippet it should be clear that, unless you pass the individual quantity of each existing `commerceItem` to the request, you will simply update the quantity of each of the `commerceItem`s to the same quantity.

Here is a simplified version of updating the quantity:

```
public boolean handleUpdateItemQuantityToOrder(DynamoHttpServletRequest request, DynamoHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Order order = getOrder();

    //Get All the Commerce Items on the Order
    List<CommerceItem> commerceItems = order.getCommerceItems();
    String currentSku = "";

    // currentCommerceItem is the one that you passed from your JSP page
    String currentId = getCurrentCommerceItem();

    // Add all the existing commerce item quantities to the request
    for (CommerceItem commerceItem : commerceItems) {
        request.setParameter(commerceItem.getId(), commerceItem.getQuantity());
        if (commerceItem.getId().equals(currentId)) {
            currentSku = commerceItem.getCatalogRefId();
        }
    }

    // the quantity element is from the JSP page. Set it to the Sku you want to change on the request.
    request.setParameter(currentId, getQuantity());

    // Set the new quantity for the commerce item being updated.
    setCheckForChangedQuantity(true);

    handleSetOrderByCommerceId(request, response); // Pass the order updates to a REAL ATG method so you don't have to write it yourself

    return checkFormRedirect(getUpdateSuccessURL(), getUpdateErrorURL(), request, response);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for modifyOrder and modifyOrderByCommerceId explains it all -

**modifyOrder**

> Modify the order (accessed from the `order` property) based
>   on the changes in the request.
>       This method iterates over each of the current CommerceItems in the order and finds the current
>       quantity submitted. In addition we check to make sure that the item should even be included
>       in the order any longer. If the quantity is greater than zero we adjust the quantity in the CommerceItem
>       and the ShippingGroupCommerceItemRelationship. Otherwise we remove the CommerceItem and the
>       relationships.

**modifyOrderByCommerceId**

> Modify the order (accessed from the `order` property)
>   based on the changes in
>       the request.  This method iterates over each of the current CommerceItems in the order and
>       finds the current quantity submitted. Note, this replaces the use of modifyOrder method
>       because that method made use of the catalogRefId to identify the commerce item to be
>       modified instead of using the commerce item id itself.  In addition we check to make sure
>       that the item should even be included in the order any longer. If the quantity is greater
>       than zero we adjust the quantity in the CommerceItem and the
>       ShippingGroupCommerceItemRelationship. Otherwise we remove the CommerceItem and the
>       relationships.

You can also look at the source code of `CartModifierFormHandler` at

ATG_INSTALL_LOCATION\DCS\src\Java\atg\commerce\order\purchase

Answer (score 0):

if you want update quantity of specific item in cart page you will need to pass quantity as stated below :

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="3" name="<dsp:valueof param='commerceItem.id'/>" value="<dsp:valueof param='commerceItem.quantity'/>">
```

update cart button:

```
<dsp:input bean="CartModifierFormHandler.moveToPurchaseInfoByCommerceId" type="submit" value="Update Cart" id="sbmtUpdateCart" />
```

moveToPurchaseInfoByCommerceId in above code will fetch the quantity by commerceItem Id from request parameter and updates the commerceitem with the quantity.

Atg does:

```
int qty=request.getParameter(commerceItem.id);
commerceItem.setQuantity(qty);
```

and the quantity of comerce item is update.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more concise than @radimpe's answer. I have added error handling for "order". I have also expect a single request parameter, the commerce item ID as the name and the quantity as the value (e.g. "ci10000099":"2"). There does not seem to be a need to call *setCheckForChangedQuantity(true)*, unless I am missing something.

```
Order order = getOrder();
if (order == null) {
    String msg = formatUserMessage(MSG_NO_ORDER_TO_MODIFY, pRequest, pResponse);
    throw new ServletException(msg);
}

// Add the commerce items and their quantities to the request so that they are not removed from the order
List<CommerceItem> commerceItems = order.getCommerceItems();
for (CommerceItem commerceItem : commerceItems) {
    if (pRequest.getParameter(commerceItem.getId()) == null) {
        pRequest.setParameter(commerceItem.getId(), commerceItem.getQuantity());
    }
}

handleSetOrderByCommerceId(pRequest, pResponse);

return checkFormRedirect(getUpdateSuccessURL(), getUpdateErrorURL(), pRequest, pResponse);
```

Comment: You should use the `setCheckForChangedQuantity` flag to inform the formhandler to read the new quantity from the request and not from the item itself. If you don't set this it will do an `item.getQuantity()` instead. So looking at the code you've given above it does the same thing, you read the quantity from the `commerceItem` and not from the request so you won't be changing the quantity on the order.